# How do I configure passport.authentication to accept Guest user?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport-local

My login/authenticate user functionality ensures that my users are logged in before they can use any of my website's resources, I would like to offer my users the alternative to enjoy the website resources even as `a guest user`.

My `login/authentication` function, using the `passport` module works perfectly, by restricting all users from accessing any of the website resources unless they are logged in, how do I configure my `post` in express to ignore the user authentication, if they **choose** to continue as a guest user?

Find below my simplified `HTML` form:

```
<form action="/userLogin" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
  <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>

  <button type="submit" name="guestUser" value="guestUser"> Continue as guest </button> 
  <button type="submit" name="login" value="login"> Login </button> 

</form>
```

Id like to draw your attention to the **values** that both the **Login** button and the **Continue as guest** buttons carry with them, as this I will be using this in express.

Currently, clicking on either the `Login` & `Continue as guest` buttons both lead to the user authentication function as seen in the following code.

```
.post( passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/enjoyResources',
        failureRedirect: '/userLogin'
    }) 
);
```

In an attempt to get `Continue as guest` to work, I tried changing the code to the following:

```
    .post( (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.Login === 'Login'){
        console.log("User clicked on: Login");
         
        passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/enjoyResources',
        failureRedirect: '/advertiserLogin'
    })

    }
                           
    if(req.body.PostAnAd === 'PostAnAd'){
        console.log("User clicked on: Continue as Guest");

        res.redirect('/enjoyResources');
    }
}
```

The code above, naturally disables `passport.authenticate` functionality.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: You are probably looking for an `optionalAuthGuard` which ultimately attaches authenticated data if provided, or else just sends the request through without attaching => guest

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum Thanks, am having a difficult time finding any documentation about `optionalAuthGuard` any links you can refer me to?